# How do I render a class (react component) passed as a prop?

Tags: reactjs

```
import SomeComponent from 'Somewheere';




class MyPage {
    render() {
        return '<OtherComponent AcceptsSomeClass={SomeComponent} />';
    }
}
```

in `OtherComponent` I want to be able to do

```
class OtherComponent {
    render() {
        
        return <this.props.AcceptsSomeClass open={true} someOtherProp={123}/>;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to render `SomeComponent` inside `OtherComponent`. I know I can just pass a node or a function. But I've seen a library before that accepts a class like this and I want to pass the class so that I can control it more in `OtherComponent` instead of deciding how it renders in MyPage and passing it thee node/function.

In other words I want to pass a class (react component) as a prop and then be able to use it in the JSX.

Comment: have you tried  children: *{this.props.children}* ?

Comment: components are passed as props when we are talking about higher order components. What do you wanna do here? I will post an example using HOC

Answer (score 0):

An example of which you can pass components as props is when you are dealing with HOC (higher-order-components)

I use HOC to handle HTTP requests, for instance, using a modal to pop up on the screen with the loading / error when fetching /putting data, or authentication.

I will present you with a simple example:

```
import React from 'react'
import Modal from 'modal' //this would be a modal covering the screen

const httpHandler = WrappedComponent => {

  const wrappedComponent = props => {
     //handle some logic here, coded here, or as a result from some middleware 
  
  return (
   <Fragment>
     <Modal>...</Modal> //handle the HTTP async stuff here, like loading,
                        //or authentication, or an error message
     <WrappedComponent {...props} />
   </Fragment>
  )
}}
```

You can call this inside a Component like this when you export another component

```
//all of the component stuff above
export default httpHandler(WrappedComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is that we are passing a function that renders a component, then we can call that function inside the `OtherComponent` to render it there.

```js
class MyPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <OtherComponent AcceptsSomeClass={() => <SomeComponent />} />
  }
}

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Content inside OtherComponent</p>
        {this.props.AcceptsSomeClass()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyPage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```